# Converting Decimal to Hex does not work for 8020224

Tags: javascript

Alright, so the issue is the fact that other codes that I have tried with this function works fine, but for some reason putting in this specific decimal code doesn't work.

However, first off let me give you the current code I have to counter this.

```
function hexlify(num) {
    const bs = num.toString(16);
    // rearrange because CSS hex str are yolo.
    return '#' + (bs.substr(4, 2) + bs.substr(2, 2) + bs.substr(0, 2)).padStart(6, '0');
}
```

That's a code a friend of mine gave me, though I wasn't able to ask him why exactly it's required to  rearrange them and for others it's not required. So, can someone please explain to me exactly **WHY** it is required to rearrange it? Like I've seen other codes like:

```
let hexString = yourNumber.toString(16);
if (hexString.length % 2) {
  hexString = '0' + hexString;
}
```

Which I found from the other StackOverflow questions.  It works, until of course I put in the decimal: 8020224.

---

Output gives me: `#7A6200` instead of `#00627A`.

So the question is once again, **WHY** exactly is this happening. Every other decimal I've given works just fine here are just a short list.

- 65535
- 5329233
- 4802889
- ...

---

Comment: Why should the correct answer be `00627A`? that is `25210` base 10 (i.e. `(6 * 16**3) + (2 * 16**2) + (7 * 16) + (10)`).

Comment: Are you familiar with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Illustration)? The `hexlify` function appears to behave similar to little-endianness, with the input number computed from `(green * 65535) + (blue * 255) + red`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski It seems like it, but I got my answer today. Apparently it's the format `aaggbbrr`. Not sure if that's the same  thing you're talking about.

Comment: This would be easier to test if you called it with `0x123456` and check that you get `#123456` back out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I was able to ask my friend about this and he answered with this:

> Some graphics APIs and toolkits and whatnot, which the flight standard probably is keen on, use hex colors where the byte ordering is: #aabbggrr. This sort of convention has been going on forever. With this, the color (R: 255, G:0, B: 127, A: 6) would turn out to be: #067f00ff.
>
> CSS and Photoshop and ... on the other hand use ordering: #aarrggbb (blue and red switched), so we've got to simply switch those two bytes in the hex output in order for the canvas to parse the CSS color as what we're desiring.

So I suppose the decimal to hex converting was not necessarily "incorrect", it was just not the hex I was looking for. I guess that resolves this mystery. (at least for me)

Answer (score 2):

The second snippet of code you provided returns `7a6100` when provided `8020224` as the input, which is correct.

The output you are expecting `00627A`, corresponds to the decimal value `25210`.